# How to retrieve the most recent row based on multiple rows with logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a table like this:

| JobID | dateCreated | dateLastUpdated | JobTargetCompleteDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2006-01-26 16:35:00 | 2006-01-26 16:35:00 | NULL |
| 123 | 2006-01-16 14:36:00 | 2006-01-26 12:43:00 | NULL |
| 123 | 2006-01-16 14:28:00 | 2006-03-21 16:20:00 | 2006-02-28 00:00:00 |
| 456 | 2022-12-20 10:46:00 | 2023-02-10 14:14:00 | NULL |
| 456 | 2022-12-16 17:11:00 | 2023-02-10 14:14:00 | 2023-02-10 00:00:00 |
| 789 | 2023-03-29 09:51:00 | 2023-04-06 14:22:00 | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 |
| 789 | 2023-03-27 15:17:00 | 2023-03-29 09:58:00 | NULL |

Desired results:

| JobID | dateCreated | dateLastUpdated | JobTargetCompleteDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2006-01-16 14:28:00 | 2006-03-21 16:20:00 | 2006-02-28 00:00:00 |
| 456 | 2022-12-20 10:46:00 | 2023-02-10 14:14:00 | NULL |
| 789 | 2023-03-29 09:51:00 | 2023-04-06 14:22:00 | 2023-05-31 00:00:00 |

The logic is:

- if a datelastUpdated is greater than any dateCreated for a jobid, then retrieve that record.
- They can be occasions whereby a jobid can have the same dateLastUpdated - in that case the record with the most recent dateCreated should be retrieved (456 in the example).

I have tried a SQL Group By and a Max on the columns, but this brings throug

```
SELECT JobId,
       MAX(dateCreated) AS dateCreated,
       MAX(dateLastUpdated) AS dateLastUpdated,
       MAX(targetCompletionDate) AS JobTargetCompleteDate
FROM dbo.tblJobHead
GROUP BY JobId
```

But that brings in the incorrect value for JobID 456.

I've also tried a RowNumber, but that brings in the incorrect value for jobid 123:

```
SELECT t1.JobId,
       t1.dateCreated,
       t1.dateLastUpdated,
       t1.JobtargetCompleteDate,
       t1.rn
FROM
(
    SELECT JobId,
           dateCreated,
           dateInstructed,
           dateLastUpdated,
           JobtargetCompleteDate,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobId ORDER BY dateCreated DESC,dateLastUpdated desc) rn
    FROM dbo.tblJobHead
) t1
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Don't the "123" record to be retrieve is `123 2006-01-16 14:36:00.000 2006-01-26 12:43:00.000 NULL` ?

Comment: When using row_number, shouldn't you reverse the order by's to:  `partition by jobId order by dateLastUpdated desc, dateCreated desc`

Comment: @Delta no because the 2006-03-21 16:20:00 the most recent record

Comment: @Isolated of course! The answer was right there - thank you

Answer (score 0):

@Isolated got right, you need to reverse the fields in your `ROW_NUMBER()`.

You then need to select only the rows where `dateLastUpdated` is greater than any `dateCreated` based on the same `JobId`.

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP (
    JobId int,
    dateCreated DATETIME,
    dateLastUpdated DATETIME,
    JobTargetCompleteDate DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO #TMP
VALUES
(123, '2006-01-26 16:35:00', '2006-01-26 16:35:00', NULL),
(123, '2006-01-16 14:36:00', '2006-01-26 12:43:00', NULL),
(123, '2006-01-16 14:28:00', '2006-03-21 16:20:00', '2006-02-28 00:00:00'),
(456, '2022-12-20 10:46:00', '2023-02-10 14:14:00', NULL),
(456, '2022-12-16 17:11:00', '2023-02-10 14:14:00', '2023-02-10 00:00:00'),
(789, '2023-03-29 09:51:00', '2023-04-06 14:22:00', '2023-05-31 00:00:00'),
(789, '2023-03-27 15:17:00', '2023-03-29 09:58:00', NULL);

WITH TMP_TBL AS (
    SELECT JobId,
           dateCreated,
           dateLastUpdated,
           JobtargetCompleteDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobId ORDER BY dateLastUpdated DESC,dateCreated desc) rn
    FROM #TMP AS tmp1
    WHERE dateLastUpdated > (SELECT MIN(dateCreated) FROM #TMP AS tmp2 WHERE tmp1.JobId = tmp2.JobId)
)
SELECT t1.JobId,
       t1.dateCreated,
       t1.dateLastUpdated,
       t1.JobtargetCompleteDate
FROM TMP_TBL AS t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

That results in :

| JobId | dateCreated | dateLastUpdated | JobtargetCompleteDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2006-01-16 14:28:00.000 | 2006-03-21 16:20:00.000 | 2006-02-28 00:00:00.000 |
| 456 | 2022-12-20 10:46:00.000 | 2023-02-10 14:14:00.000 | NULL |
| 789 | 2023-03-29 09:51:00.000 | 2023-04-06 14:22:00.000 | 2023-05-31 00:00:00.000 |

Comment: If I run the above I receive: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'

Comment: mb, `With` needs a semicolon before (so here after the `INSERT`statement)

Comment: also, check out [LAST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)